# How to use for in php create multi function

Tags: php, function

If have for loop :

```
for ($i=1; $i <=9 ; $i++) { 

function add_field_func_$i()
{ 
    $show = "This is function" . $i ;
} // end function

} // end for
```

I got an error where the name function, how to append the variable $i value to the name of the function.
Please help me, Thanks

Comment: This is really bad practice to create so many multiple functions.(While it seems one function can do the job if you try to describe a bit more regarding what you actually want to achieve?)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign looping variable to function name like that way.
Why do you had to make looping function?
Why don't you just put the parameter to the function?

Example :

```
function main(){ 
    for ($i=1; $i <=9 ; $i++) {
        add_field_func($i);
    }
}

function add_field_func($i){
    // your code here
}
```

May I know what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual scenario as very little information is shared. maybe you can do this ---

```
function add_field_func_n ($i){
  switch (i) {
      case 1:
        // code
        break;
      case 2:
        // code
        break;
      case 3:
        // code
        break;
        //..... as many you want
     default:
        // code
}
```

}